# RHEL sends mail as myhost.localdomain but I don't want the localdomain suffix/FQDN

Tags: email, postfix, redhat, configuration, rhel7

I have several machines that used to run Ubuntu 10.04.  The OS were changed to RHEL7.  After the change, programs like `cron` and `mail` send mail as `myuser@myhost.localdomain` whereas on Ubuntu it was `myuser@myhost`.  I prefer the Ubuntu way, without the `localdomain` suffix, and would like my RedHat installs to work the same way.  How can I do this?

`/etc/hosts` looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
1.2.3.4 myhost.example.com myhost
```

`hostname -f` shows `myhost.example.com`; `hostname` shows `myhost` (all of which seems OK, and the same as on Ubuntu).

Comment: Are you using postfix or sendmail?

Comment: @chicks: postfix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The program which modified the sender was postfix.

1. By default crontab/mail will use username as email sender **without domain parts**. So the sender becomes **myuser**
2. Because postfix sees sender doesn't domain name, by default postfix will append hostname as its domain. See parameter [append_at_myorigin](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#append_at_myorigin) and [myorigin](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#myorigin) in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`. The sender becomes **myuser@myhost**
3. Because `myhost` isn't FQDN. So it will append `localdomain` in sender. See parameter [append_dot_mydomain](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#append_dot_mydomain) and [mydomain](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydomain) in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`. The sender becomes **myuser@myhost.localdomain**

### Solution

- Set parameter `append_dot_mydomain` in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` become **no**.
- Restart postfix

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure from where the crontab picks up the hostname part of the from email address, but one thing that you can do is to add a `MAILFROM=` line on the very top of the crontab so that it will send the email from the address mentioned in the `MAILFROM=` line.

```
[root@mercury01 ~]# crontab -l
MAILFROM=root@mercury.example.com

*/10 * * * * sh /usr/local/src/disk-usage

[root@qa3app01 ~]#
```

Comment: That can fix `cron` but not any of the other programs like `mail`.